# How to affect other elements when menu item is clicked

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class, siblings

I have created a custom non sticky sub menu that I want to appear when a certain menu item is clicked on. I'm having it scrolled to location when clicked and I've decided I want to control visibility with the height attribute. What is the correct way of doing this with CSS?

---

Also this is my first question ever. I appreciate tips on asking better questions.

The structure looks something like this

```css
#submenu {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu-trigger:focus~#submenu {
  height: 134px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="submenu-trigger" href="#submenu">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Placed outside to follow page scroll -->
  <section>
    <div id="submenu">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main>
    …
  </main>
</div>
```

---

Edit: It seems this isn't possible with CSS. How do I get the submenu to retract using JS when the main menu item is no longer in focus?

Edit 2: Implemented a variant of @[biberman's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66933367/15545947) at https://ensjotannklinikk.no/forside-wip/. Here's the differences in the live version:

- **"Behandlinger"** = the menu item in question
- `.behandlinger-meny` instead of `#submenu`
- `.behandlinger-item` instead of `.submenu-trigger`
- `55px` instead of `auto`, to preserve CSS transition

```js
    document.querySelector('.behandlinger-item').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var submenu = document.querySelector('.behandlinger-meny');
            submenu.style.height = '55px';
    });
```

It's really close, kudos to @biberman.

Only thing missing is

- <s>Having it stay open on every click (not toggle on and off).</s> Figured myself.
- <s>Toggle off (back to height 0) when clicking anywhere else but `.behandlinger-meny` and `.behandlinger-item`</s> @biberman strikes again.
- This fix doesn't work on mobile. [New question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66937315/how-to-make-addeventlistener-click-work-on-mobile-menu).

Thank you so much, Stack Overflow!

Comment: You can achieve this with JS.

Comment: *I appreciate tips on asking better questions.* Please [edit] your question to include a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). So your question includes a [mre].

Comment: @Developer thanks. I'd love to learn to do it in CSS, if that's even possible

Comment: Your main menu is in the `<header>` and your submen is somewhere else on the page in a `<section>`. For reason that the submenu is not in the html flow it seems not possible with css only in the html structure you posted. Javascrript is the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can easily be done with js (in a script tag or a seperate js file). You just need an event listener for 'click' and a small function for changing the height:

```js
document.querySelector('.submenu-trigger').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var submenu = document.querySelector('#submenu');
    submenu.style.height = submenu.style.height == 'auto' ? 0 : 'auto';
});
```

```css
#submenu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.submenu-trigger:focus ~ #submenu {
    height: 134px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="submenu-trigger" href="#submenu">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <section>
    <div id="submenu">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <main>
    …
  </main>
</div>
```

---

If you search a solution without extra javascript, may be you could reduce it to a minimum and do it inline. (it is better not to mix html structure and programcode, but it works):

```css
#submenu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="submenu-trigger" href="#submenu" onclick="document.querySelector('#submenu').style.height = (document.querySelector('#submenu').style.height == 'auto') ? '0' : 'auto';">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <section>
    <div id="submenu">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
  
  <main>
    …
  </main>
</div>
```

---

If you want to close the menu when you click somewhere else (not .submenu-trigger and not #submenu) or when you press 'Esc', then you need two more event listeners. But this is not inline:

```js
var submenu = document.querySelector('#submenu');
var menuTrigger = document.querySelector('.submenu-trigger');

function isChild(item, parentItem) {
    while (item != undefined && item != null && item.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'BODY'){
        if (item == parentItem){
            return true;
        }
        item = item.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}

menuTrigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    submenu.style.height = 'auto';
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if ( !isChild(e.target, menuTrigger) && !isChild(e.target, submenu) ) {
        submenu.style.height = 0;
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if ( e.key == 'Escape' ) {
        submenu.style.height = 0;
    }
});
```

```css
#submenu {
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="submenu-trigger" href="#submenu">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
    <div id="submenu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </section>

    <main>
        ...
    </main>
</div>
```

---

jQuery example:

```js
var submenu = $('#submenu');

$('.submenu-trigger').on('click', function() {
  submenu.css('height', 'auto');
});

$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('.submenu-trigger') &&
    !$(e.target).parents().is('#submenu')) {
    submenu.css('height', 0);
  }
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.key == 'Escape') {
    submenu.css('height', 0);
  }
});
```

```css
#submenu {
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="submenu-trigger" href="#submenu">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div id="submenu">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main>
    ...
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've closed them now. This is good, but I guess it doesn't automatically retract  when the menu item is no longer in focus?

Comment: There was nothing about focus in your question, just about click. So please be more precise (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: I was hoping to achieve this with CSS, then it would go without saying. But I appreciate your point and I will try to be more clear about what I actually want, not just what I imagine the solution to look like

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If it helps: you can reduce the function to a minimum and use it with ```onclick=""``` (in your trigger tag). It's a bit dirty but it works...

Comment: It works beautifully! Thank you so much! Any chance you know what it takes to make it work on mobile?

Comment: This is answered in an other question ;)>