# How to make addEventListener 'click' work on two menu items with same class

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, addeventlistener

Page: https://ensjotannklinikk.no/

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dyah459t/8/)

The first menu item called "**Behandlinger**" is set up with this JS (courtesy of [biberman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15377355/biberman)) to make the submenu emerge and retract properly.

```js
var submenu = document.querySelector('.behandlinger-meny');
var menuTrigger = document.querySelector('.behandlinger-item');

//javascript version of jQuery isChild()
function isChild(item, parentItem) {
    while (item != undefined && item != null && item.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'BODY'){
        if (item == parentItem){
            return true;
        }
        item = item.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}

menuTrigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    submenu.style.height = '55px';
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if ( !isChild(e.target, menuTrigger) && !isChild(e.target, submenu) ) {
        submenu.style.height = 0;
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if ( e.key == 'Escape' ) {
        submenu.style.height = 0;
    }
});
```

**Why is this not working on mobile?** I wish for the submenu (`.behandlinger-meny`) height set to `55px` when the menu item Behandlinger (`.behandlinger-item`) is clicked. It works perfectly, except **not on the menu item click on mobile**.

---

Realized the mobile menu has a `<nav>` of its own, which may affect the event listener. I have updated both the fiddle and the simplified structure below as well as the core question. Seems really close to a simple solution now.

Simplified structure:

```css
.behandlinger-meny {
    height: 0;
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>

    <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="mobile-main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="mobile-item behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <section> <!-- Separated to follow page scroll -->
    <div id="behandlinger"> <!-- Scroll to position on item click -->
      <nav class="behandlinger-meny">
        <script></script> <!-- Script in question  -->
        <ul>
          <li><a>Sub item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main>
    …
  </main>
</div>
```

Runnable version:

```js
var submenu = document.querySelector('.behandlinger-meny');
var menuTrigger = document.querySelector('.behandlinger-item');

//javascript version of jQuery isChild()
function isChild(item, parentItem) {
    while (item != undefined && item != null && item.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'BODY'){
        if (item == parentItem){
            return true;
        }
        item = item.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}

menuTrigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    submenu.style.height = '55px';
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if ( !isChild(e.target, menuTrigger) && !isChild(e.target, submenu) ) {
        submenu.style.height = 0;
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if ( e.key == 'Escape' ) {
        submenu.style.height = 0;
    }
});
```

```css
.behandlinger-meny {
    height: 0;
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>

    <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="mobile-main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="mobile-item behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <section> <!-- Separated to follow page scroll -->
    <div id="behandlinger"> <!-- Scroll to position on item click -->
      <nav class="behandlinger-meny">
        <script></script> <!-- Script in question  -->
        <ul>
          <li><a>Sub item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main>
    …
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested your page https://ensjotannklinikk.no/forside-wip with firefox on android and with my windows convertible and it worked in destop mode. So the touch event is perfectly interpreted as 'click'. But in mobile mode your menu has another style (hamburger etc.), so i think it's something with your css. --- Or could it be, that your javascript (where the event listener is declared) is dependent on screen resolution/media query (could wordpress do something like that)?

Comment: I see now that the mobile menu is a different ```<nav>``` and there are in fact two different ```li.behandlinger-item``` in the same document, the mobile version coming in second. Could this be the issue?

Comment: That was the bug ;) -> The example for the other question was just for one trigger. I answered this question here with an updated example for multiple triggers...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you have two triggers and your event listener is only attached to the first with `querySelector` the second trigger has no listener.

You can use `querySelectorAll` and attach the event listener in a for loop to each selected trigger. Because you want a transition you have to use 'max-height' instead of 'height' since transition doesn't work with height.

For closing the submenu when clicking somewhere else (except trigger or submenu) i made a function *isRelated()* that checks if the click target is the trigger itself, the submenu or a child of both.

**Working example** with multiple triggers (jQuery example below):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var submenu = document.querySelector('.behandlinger-meny');
  var menuTrigger = document.querySelectorAll('.behandlinger-item');

  function isRelated(item, parentSelector) {
    while (item != undefined && item != null && item.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'BODY') {
      parents = document.querySelectorAll(parentSelector);
      for (i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        if (item == parents[i]) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      item = item.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < menuTrigger.length; i++) {
    menuTrigger[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      submenu.style.maxHeight = '1000px';
    });
  }

  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (!isRelated(e.target, '.behandlinger-item') && !isRelated(e.target, '.behandlinger-meny')) {
      submenu.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Escape') {
      submenu.style.maxHeight = 0;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}

.behandlinger-meny {
  max-height: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <header>
    <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="mobile-main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="mobile-item behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div id="behandlinger">
      <nav class="behandlinger-meny">
        <ul>
          <li><a>Sub item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main>
    …
  </main>

</div>
```

---

**jQuery example:**

```js
$().ready(function() {

  var submenu = $('.behandlinger-meny');
  
  $('.behandlinger-item').on('click', function() {
    submenu.css('maxHeight', '1000px');
  });

  $('body').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).parents().is('.behandlinger-item') 
    && !$(e.target).parents().is('.behandlinger-meny')) {
      submenu.css('maxHeight', 0);
    }
  });

  $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'Escape') {
      submenu.css('maxHeight', 0);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}

.behandlinger-meny {
  max-height: 0;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">

  <header>
    <nav class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <nav class="mobile-main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li class="mobile-item behandlinger-item"><a href="#behandlinger">Behandlinger</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div id="behandlinger">
      <nav class="behandlinger-meny">
        <ul>
          <li><a>Sub item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Sub item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <main>
    …
  </main>

</div>
```